# Filter and convert `list option` to `list`?

Tags: f#

I have the following code which will return a `seq` of `DownloadLink` for these Urls that can be parsed.

```
type DownloadLink = { Url: string; Period: DateTime }   

nodes |> Seq.map (fun n ->
    let url = n.Attributes.["href"].Value
    match url with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "[a-zA-Z](?<period>\d{4})\.txt" [period] ->
        { Url = url; Period = period }
    | _ ->
        printfn "Cannot parse %s" url // Error
        )
```

However, I got the following error at the `printfn`. What's right way to implement it? Should I make it a `list option` first and then filter out these `None` items?

```
Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string -> DownloadLink    
but given a
    string -> unit    
The type 'DownloadLink' does not match the type 'unit'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that if you have something like

```
match x with
|true -> A
|false -> B
```

the type of `A` and `B` must be the same.

There is actually a build in function that combines the map and filter using `Some` that you had though of - use `Seq.choose` like so

```
nodes |> Seq.choose (fun n ->
    let url = n.Attributes.["href"].Value
    match url with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "[a-zA-Z](?<period>\d{4})\.txt" [period] ->
        Some ({ Url = url; Period = period })
    | _ ->
        printfn "Cannot parse %s" url // Error
        None
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. `Seq.choose` is so useful here. Otherwise, I was thinking creating `seq option` first, filtering out `None` items, and then remapping back to `seq<DownloadLink>` from `seq<DownloadLink option>`.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from `Seq.choose`, you can also nicely solve the problem using sequence expressions - where you can use `yield` to return result in one branch, but do not have to produce a value in another branch:

```
seq { for n in nodes do
        let url = n.Attributes.["href"].Value
        match url with
        | Helper.ParseRegex "[a-zA-Z](?<period>\d{4})\.txt" [period] ->
            yield { Url = url; Period = period }
        | _ ->
            printfn "Cannot parse %s" url }
```

Aside, I would not recommend doing a side effect (printing) as part of your processing code. If you want to report errors, it might be better to return an option (or define a type which is either `Success` or `Error of string`) so that the error reporting is separated from processing.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know there is an alternative way to do it. Eventually I want to log the errors (in a database table or text file, maybe the succeeded one too). What's the best way to implement logging (it's also a side effect) in F#?

Comment: I think logging inside sequence expression is fine - printing is user-visible side-effect, so it makes more sense to handle it nicely, but logging is something that is more for internal purposes - so I do not think there is a problem when its done as part of other computations (that's kind of the point of logging :-))

Comment: I plan to use async logging from this github project. https://gist.github.com/ppanyukov/2026328 Is it good to handle both printing and logging?